# Remove question mark ? using jQuery .replace

Tags: jquery, regex

Trying to add a class to a div from the name inside another div after replacing some unwated characters but cannot remove a question mark.

```
<div class="add-class-to-this">
    Class gets added here
</div>

<div class="get-class-name-from-contents-of-this">
    Name containing, question mark?
</div>

$('.add-class-to-this').addClass($('.get-name-from-contents-of-this').html().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/,/g, '').replace(/?/g, ''));
```

'Name containing question mark?' makes lowercase, replaces the spaces with hyphens, removes the commas and then removes the question mark, but the question mark does not remove.

When I run through my javascript compiler I get the error:

```
Invalid regular expression: /?/: Nothing to repeat
```

Comment: You don't need a regular expression to search for a constant string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first regex must be:

```
.replace(/\s/g, '-') // Replace the spaces
```

The third should be escaping the regex:

```
.replace(/\?/g, '-') // ? is a regex reserved character.
```

**Console:**

```
» "Name containing, question mark?".toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '-').replace(/,/g, '').replace(/\?/g, '')
« "name-containing-question-mark"
```

[image]